# Why Not Just Replace All the Fan Blades?

Tags: turbofan, boeing-777

It looks like operators will have to remove all their P&W powered B777s from service until they have checked the engines.  Since the problem seems to be fatigue (which is a function of time) in a front fan blade, why not just replace all the blades in the front fan while you have it in maintenance?  What would be the cost of that compared to an inspection?

Comment: The cost would be significant. Those blades are usually inspected one-by-one at one of the checks, and any failing blades are replaced. Replacing an entire fleet of blades would be huge, especially since you need to disassemble them anyway.

Comment: How do you expect that replacing the whole engine fan is less expensive than an inspection?

Comment: It would probably take P&W a ***really*** long time to produce enough blades to replace every one in service on every engine on every 777 in the world. They're not cheap to produce, and it would be an immense expense to have thousands of them sitting unused in a warehouse, expecting (hoping) to never need most of them, as a "just in case" contingency.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply I thought replacing would be cheaper than inspection, I was thinking more along the lines of "the blades already have thousands of hours on them, even those that test ok may be getting near the end of their life, why not replace them all now then you won't have to worry about them for a long time."

Comment: "why not replace them all now then you won't have to worry about them for a long time" ? Well, just because they may have 1000's hours [MTTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures) (mean time to failure), that's not a point in time; it's a distribution for the [Failure rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure_rate). That's why everything gets inspected on regular schedules and after unexpected events. If you replaced them all at 80% MTTF, you'd be discarding good parts and still have failures. Discovering imminent failure by inspection way cheaper than by observation.

Comment: @Ron Ralph and Ian.  I agree with all three of you.  In hindsight it was not a very good question.